# Serializing canvas that has been scaled for a small viewscreen

Tags: json, canvas, konvajs

I have created a responsive canvas following the example in the documentation: https://konvajs.github.io/docs/sandbox/Responsive_Canvas.html.

The user has the ability to save the canvas to their library; I create a JSON text file and a PNG of the canvas. The PNG is used to display the saved canvas in the users library and the Json is used to load the canvas when it is selected from the library.

My problem is the canvas is saved based on the current responsive size, but I need the saved version to be the default `width x height` of `500 x 667`.

Here is my code for scaling the canvas:

```
function fitStageIntoParentContainer() {
    var stageParent = document.querySelector('#stage-parent');
    // now we need to fit stage into parent
    var stageParentWidth = stageParent.offsetWidth;
    // to do this we need to scale the stage
    var scale = stageParentWidth / width;
    if ((width * scale) < width) {
        stage.width(width * scale);
        stage.height(height * scale);
        stage.scale({ x: scale, y: scale });
        stage.draw();        
    }
}
```

Here is my code for saving the canvas:

```
function saveLabel($title, $continue) {
    var elGrid = stage.find('.gridlayer');
    if (elGrid.length) elGrid.destroy();  

    var $json = stage.toJSON();
    var $dataURL = stage.toDataURL('image/png');
    console.log($json);
    console.log($dataURL);
    saveLabelAjax($json, $dataURL, $title, $continue, label_maker);
}
```

I've tried changing the stage width, height and scale before getting the Json and PNG, but I just end up with an blank PNG.

Here is the code I tried:

```
function saveLabel($title, $continue) {
    var elGrid = stage.find('.gridlayer');
    if (elGrid.length) elGrid.destroy();

    var currentWidth = stage.width();
    var currentHeight = stage.height();
    var currentXScale = stage.scaleX();
    var currentYScale = stage.scaleY();
    stage.setWidth(width);
    stage.setHeight(height);
    stage.scale({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    stage.draw();
    var $json = stage.toJSON();
    var $dataURL = stage.toDataURL('image/png');
    console.log($json);
    console.log($dataURL);
    stage.setWidth(currentWidth);
    stage.setHeight(currentHeight);
    stage.scale({ x: currentXScale, y: currentYScale });
    stage.draw();

    //console.log(json);
    saveLabelAjax($json, $dataURL, $title, $continue, label_maker);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update: I changed the 'stage.scale({ x: 0, y: 0 });' to 'stage.scale({ x: 1, y: 1 });' and I no longer get a blank PNG, but my PNG is not being saved at 500 x 667 it is being saved as 625 x 833. I replaced the width and height variables with 500 and 667, but it still saved the PNG as 625 x 833. The PNG is used to print out a label for a bottle and it needs to be 500 x 667 in size.

Comment: You have this line `stage.setWidth(width);`. What is `width`? What it equals to?

Comment: width is set to 500; `var width = 500;
var height = 667;`

Comment: The code looks fine. I may help if you can create a small reproducible demo.